# How do I cleanup local RTC metadata

Tags: metadata, rtc, ibm-jazz

My current client is using RTC for a small number of projects built via Jenkins. I've noticed that there's a ~/.jazz-scm directory in the Jenkins user's home that fills up over time with a log file, e.g. ~/.jazz-scm/scratch/0/.metadata/.log  (sometimes the numeric directory is something other than 0).

Unfortunately, the Jenkins user's home directory is on a relatively small partition (the important Jenkins stuff is on a separate larger partition).

Is there a way to rotate and/or blitz these logs through RTC?  Is it safe to simply delete these from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `~/.jazz-scm/scratch/0/.metadata/.log` (sometimes the numeric directory is something other than 0).

As [explained in this tip](https://jazz.net/library/article/533/), those folders depends on the number of scm processes running:

> The configuration area contains a directory named scratch which holds up to ten numbered directories (ie, 0, 1, 2, etc).
>   If there are ten scm processes running, they will exhaust those numbered directories. You can check if the directories have been exhausted by running lsof on the OSGi lock in each of the numbered directories. The lock is found at `.metadata/lock`.

But to your question:

> You can move the configuration area by specifying `scm --config /path/to/non-NFS/filesystem` on every invocation, or (in 3.0) specifying the **`SCM_CONFIG_DIRECTORY`** environment variable.